Laravel 11 Unit Test - Call to a member function connection() on null
I tried creating a unit test for my User service class, however when I run php artisan test this errors are thrown, I have no idea about this since I'm a newbie in unit testing.
The code works perfectly in controllers, this errors only happens in tests:
This is my UserTest class:
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Services\UserService;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $userService;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->userService = app(UserService::class);
    }

    public function test_create_user(): void
    {
        $userArray = [
            'nome' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => '2V4e3@example.com',
            'login' => 'johndoe',
            'status' => 1
        ];

        $user = $this->userService->create($userArray);

        $this->assertTrue($user->email === $userArray['email']);
    }
}

Command executed:
php artisan test
Error received:
 FAIL  Tests\Unit\UserTest
  ⨯ create user                                                                                                                                                0.05s  
  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
   FAILED  Tests\Unit\UserTest > create user                                                                                                                  Error   
  Call to a member function connection() on null

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1850
    1846▕      * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
    1847▕      */
    1847▕      */
    1848▕     public static function resolveConnection($connection = null)
    1849▕     {
  ➜ 1850▕         return static::$resolver->connection($connection);
    1851▕     }


Have you properly configured your testing environment with either the oh-unit.xml or .env.testing? As noted, you need to run php artisan config:clear before you test

You didn't provide your UserService class but I think it uses a User Model which means it tries to connect to a database. This fails since in the test environment, the database details (server, port, db name, user, password) are unknown.
Please mind that the PHPUnit script will not bootstrap all these »magic« environment details like Laravel does.
So, the Model class can't set up the connection (it equals to null).
You have to mock a database connection for testing purposes. But, it's in general difficult to test classes oder methods that require a database connection.
